# Can't Compare Name Column form Database

Tags: php, laravel, database, web, backend

I am at the admin user, which is holding the administrator role, but when I add a condition to check if the user is admin or not it will always return false. I can't find the problem.
This is my code:

So this is my roles table:
[image]

And this is my users table:
[image]

I set up the relation in my user model, and a condition in the END OF THE CODE which will check if the user is admin or not:

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
 *
 * @var array<int, string>
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array<string, string>
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Role');
}

public function isAdmin() {
    if($this->role->name == 'administrator')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

}

Than I created a middleware which will allow me to go in to the admin page if the user is admin else it will redirect me to the root:
[image]

Than at the end I added the route with the controller:
[image]

And here is the controller in case you need it:
[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, so I runed:

```
return dd(Auth::user()->role->name)
```

And It rendered this in the page:

```
"administrator  "
```

I had them:

```
Auth::user()->role->name == "administrator"
```

but this means:

```
"administrator  " == "administrator"
```

The problem was that I putted an extra space when I added the role name into my database, be aware of that because its a hard mistake to see.

BE AWARE OF THE SPACING!

Now it works!!

Answer (score -1):

first of all the route action should be:

```
Route::get('/admin', [AdminController::class, 'index'];
```

than to check weather user is admin or not you can do it in middleware like this:

```
if (auth()->user()->role->name == 'administrator') {
    return $next($request);
} else {
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Ill try it now, but the route works like that too and its much easier to type!

Comment: This way is the same only shorter, but it's still not working. It returns false again!